# Google Maps Signed APK Android

Tags: android, google-maps, apk, keytool

I've got my app that works with google maps in debug mode. I create my signature.jks and then a build my signed APK. 
I retrieve the SHA1 fingerprint using che command line code

```
keytool -list -v -keystore signature.jks  -alias myalias -storepass mypass -keypass mypass
```

and I add this in my project on the google developer console.

But when I run the app on the phone it does not work. 
It is that the right procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You should setup map key in Android Manifest for all build types (debug release etc.). If you use gradle for building you can customize keys in build.gradle:

buildTypes {

```
debug {
    debuggable true
    ....
    manifestPlaceholders = [ map_key:"YOUR_DEBUG_cpq5sPasdasdasdAsVIdqK7tfG9xY" ]
}

release {
    debuggable false
    ....
    manifestPlaceholders = [ map_key:"YOUR_RELEASE_4RUFCUrHhZJWpqKGs-d1hOIxELs" ]
}
```

And in Android Manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="${map_key}" />
```

Comment: I've done this. But I put the map_key directly in the manifest. But if I make build signed apk and select debug it works, if I select release it does not work.

Comment: You should have 2 keystores. For debug and for release. Then you should generate for both - SHA1 fingerprint using command you pointed in question. Then you should register this finger prints in api console https://console.developers.google.com under APIs & auth -> Credentials. Then when you build signed apk with release key - you should use map key generated from fingerprint of release keystore, if you build using debug keystore - you should use debug map key.

Comment: the "create new" under build-generate signed APK in Android Studio is  a valid way to create a release keystore?

Comment: yes, you can find details here http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio